# In binding a derived class must I also bind all parent classes to the root class?

Tags: pybind11

True or False

> To bind a derived class in a C++ class hierarchy one must also bind all the parent classes on up to the root class.

I'm looking to bind a bunch of custom data types in a project I just started on and am looking to scope out the degree of work involved. I'm looking to bind a class that's 3 levels of derivation away from a root type.

Are there any rules of thumb for when one must also bind the parent classes to successfully bind the child classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

False

---

Let us consider a simple example:

```cpp
#include <string>

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent() { m_name = "Parent"; }

    std::string foo() { return m_name + "::foo"; }

    virtual std::string bar() { return m_name + "::bar"; }

protected:
    std::string m_name;
};

class Derived : public Parent
{
public:

    Derived() { m_name = "Derived"; }

    std::string bar() override { return m_name + "::bar (override)"; }
};
```

This you can bind the way you describe: bind the parent, the derived class will benefit from all the derived methods (you even don't have to bind the `override`):

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m)
{
    py::class_<Parent>(m, "Parent")
        .def(py::init<>(), "Constructor description")
        .def("foo", &Parent::foo, "Function description")
        .def("bar", &Parent::bar, "Function description")
        .def("__repr__", [](const Parent&) { return "<Parent>"; });

    py::class_<Derived, Parent>(m, "Derived")
        .def(py::init<>(), "Constructor description")
        .def("__repr__", [](const Derived&) { return "<Derived>"; });
}
```

Indeed

```py
import example

p = example.Parent()
print(p.foo())
print(p.bar())

d = example.Derived()
print(d.foo())
print(d.bar())
```

will print

```
Parent::foo
Parent::bar
Derived::foo
Derived::bar (override)
```

However, if you just want to bind one derived class (you don't care about the parent, nor about any of the other derived classes) you can also *just* bind the derived class you care about, without ever specifying the parent:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m)
{
    py::class_<Derived>(m, "Derived")
        .def(py::init<>(), "Constructor description")
        .def("foo", &Derived::foo, "Function description")
        .def("bar", &Derived::bar, "Function description")
        .def("__repr__", [](const Derived&) { return "<Derived>"; });
}
```

Indeed

```py
import example

d = example.Derived()
print(d.foo())
print(d.bar())
```

prints

```
Derived::foo
Derived::bar (override)
```

See [the docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html) for reference.